# is it necessary to call getConnection() in every class whenever I need to get the connection using c3Po pooling?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jsp, c3p0

I have one jsp page LoginCheck.jsp, where i want to call database to verify login details and one java class CmDatabaseConnection where i create connection pooling.

LoginCheck.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import ="java.util.Date" %>
<%@ page import ="com.wipro.clk.CmDatabaseConnection" %>
<%@ page import ="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
String userid = request.getParameter("username");
System.out.println("entered username is " +userid);
String pwd=request.getParameter("password"); 
System.out.println("entered password is " +pwd);

ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = CmDatabaseConnection.makeConnectionPool();

Connection con=dataSource.getConnection();


/* Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/CCB25", "CISADM", "CISADM"); */

//
// USE BINDS ! to avoid sql injection
// push the userid and passwd comparison to the db 
// no need to get the password and compare locally
// 
String query = "select password from cmlogin where userid=? and password=?";

PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(query);

st.setString(1,userid);
st.setString(2,pwd);

ResultSet rs  = st.executeQuery(); 
System.out.println("Size is  "+st.getFetchSize());
String pass1;

//  .next will advance if the query has any results
// 

if (rs.next()) {
pass1 = rs.getString("password");
System.out.println("value of result pass1" +pass1);

String name =request.getParameter("username");
System.out.println(name);
session.setAttribute("nam",name);
%> 
<jsp:forward page="admin.jsp"></jsp:forward>
<%
} else {
String msg="Username or password failed";
%>
<center> <p style="font-family:verdana;color:red;"> <%=msg %>
<jsp:include page="Login.jsp"></jsp:include>
<%  } 
con.close();
%>
</body>
```

CmDatabaseConnection.java

```
package com.wipro.clk;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource;


public class CmDatabaseConnection {



public static ComboPooledDataSource  makeConnectionPool()
{
ComboPooledDataSource cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
try
{

cpds.setDriverClass("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
cpds.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/CCB25");
cpds.setUser("CISADM");
cpds.setPassword("CISADM");
cpds.setMaxPoolSize(100);
cpds.setMinPoolSize(5);
cpds.setMaxStatements(180);  
cpds.setAcquireIncrement(20);


} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{

ex.printStackTrace();
}
return cpds;

}


}
```

Now my doubt is, is it necessary to call below lines whenever i want to call database?

```
ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = CmDatabaseConnection.makeConnectionPool();
Connection con=dataSource.getConnection();
```

or is it possible to acquire db connection once and use the same connection in every java/jsp file? and if we use the same in every file then is it not needed to close the connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to `get` and `close` connections.
However, the connection pool solution (e.g. `C3P0`) is taking care about connections reusing and other optimizations.

You definitely should not create a datasource on every call, it should be created once. Most probably it is better to consider abilities of your application server (e.g. `Tomcat`) for acquiring the datasource (e.g. via `JNDI`).

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to use `pool.getConnection()` everywhere you need a connection and `connection.close()` when you don't need one anymore.

That's how connection pooling works.

You create a pool of connections, get one from the pool when you need it (`pool.getConnection()`), and return it to pool when you don't need it anymore (`connection.close()`)

When using a connection pool, it will create a (new/set of) connection(s) to the database (on the go/at the same time) based on the pool implementation.

When you call, `connection.close()` it returns the connection back to the pool instead of terminating the connection (your db pool implementation takes care of this).

This is functionally similar to what you want.

I suggest [Hikari Pool](https://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/) for Java, as it is fast.

[image: Comparing Hikari CP with others]

Comment: Will it have any issue with multithreading if i call pool.getConnection() in every class?  ?

Comment: @RajeshAcharya It won't be, as long as the queries are well optimised